# Many to Many AND habtm-checkboxes help needed!

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason nothing is getting stored in my groups_user table below is the info.

My Models

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

groups_user.rb

```
class GroupsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The Entity Relationship Diagram

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsMUP.png

The Form

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2T4E.png

The view code

```
<% for group in @groups %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[group_ids][]", group.id, @user.groups.include?(group) %>
    <%= group.description %>
    <% end %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
def update 
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  params[:user][:group_ids] ||= [] 
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) flash[:success] = "User updated." 
    redirect_to @user #end 
  else 
    @title = "Edit user" 
    render 'edit' 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `groups_users` not `groups_user` and you don't have to create model for this table

Comment: `:group_ids` not `:groups_ids`

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem and it take my head blowing off:

The solution for me was simply adding this into my User Model (app/models/user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :group_ids
    [...]
end
```

Hope this helps!